# Why can't I search for a row in a pandas df using a date as part of a tuple index?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, tuples

I am trying to search a pandas df I made which has a tuple as an index. The first part of the tuple is a date and the second part is a forex pair. I've tried a few things but I can't seem to search using a date-formatted string as part of a tuple with .loc or .ix

My df looks like this:

```
                        Open   Close
(11-01-2018, AEDAUD)  0.3470  0.3448
(11-01-2018, AEDCAD)  0.3415  0.3408
(11-01-2018, AEDCHF)  0.2663  0.2656
(11-01-2018, AEDDKK)  1.6955  1.6838
(11-01-2018, AEDEUR)  0.2277  0.2261
```

Here is the complete code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

forex_11 = pd.read_csv('FOREX_20180111.csv', sep=',', parse_dates=['Date'])
forex_12 = pd.read_csv('FOREX_20180112.csv', sep=',', parse_dates=['Date'])
time_format = '%d-%m-%Y'

forex = forex_11.append(forex_12, ignore_index=False)
forex['Date'] = forex['Date'].dt.strftime(time_format)
GBP = forex[forex['Symbol'] == "GBPUSD"]
forex.index = list(forex[['Date', 'Symbol']].itertuples(index=False, name=None))

forex_open_close = pd.DataFrame(np.array(forex[['Open','Close']]), index=forex.index)
forex_open_close.columns = ['Open', 'Close']
print(forex_open_close.head())
print(forex_open_close.ix[('11-01-2018', 'GBPUSD')])
```

How do I get the row which has index ('11-01-2018', 'GBPUSD') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the Pandas [multiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html). In your case you could do the following:

```
tuples = list(data[['Date', 'Symbol']].itertuples(index=False, name=None))
data.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Date', 'Symbol'])

# And then to index
data.loc['2018-01-11', 'AEDCAD']
```

Comment: I tried using multiIndex and tbh I'd prefer it, but when I try the data.loc['2018-01-11', 'AEDCAD']  I get     axis=self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: 'the label [2018-01-11] is not in the [index]' ?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? I tested this with Pandas 0.22.0

Comment: Ok actually it's 0.21 - upgrading now

Answer (score 2):

Can you try putting the tuple in a list using brackets?

Like this:

```
print(forex_open_close.ix[[('11-01-2018', 'GBPUSD')]])
```