# Select all rows in df with the same value in second value of index tuple

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

In the same vein as my earlier question here [previous question about pandas index tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49157349/why-cant-i-search-for-a-row-in-a-pandas-df-using-a-date-as-part-of-a-tuple-inde/49157800?noredirect=1#comment85320895_49157800)

How do I access all rows of a df that have the same second element of a tuple in the index?

I have the following df which continues to the next date. It would be great to show dates with the same Symbol together.

```
                     Open   Close  Day Change
Date       Symbol
11-01-2018 AEDAUD  0.3470  0.3448     -0.0022
           AEDCAD  0.3415  0.3408     -0.0007
           AEDCHF  0.2663  0.2656     -0.0007
           AEDDKK  1.6955  1.6838     -0.0117
           AEDEUR  0.2277  0.2261     -0.0016
```

I'm having trouble selecting using all the rows with the same value in the Symbol column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(pd.__version__)

forex_11 = pd.read_csv('FOREX_20180111.csv', sep=',', parse_dates=['Date'])
forex_12 = pd.read_csv('FOREX_20180112.csv', sep=',', parse_dates=['Date'])
time_format = '%d-%m-%Y'

forex = forex_11.append(forex_12, ignore_index=False)
forex['Date'] = forex['Date'].dt.strftime(time_format)
tuples = list(forex[['Date', 'Symbol']].itertuples(index=False, name=None))
forex.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Date', 'Symbol'])
forex_open_close = pd.DataFrame(np.array(forex[['Open','Close']]), index=forex.index)
forex_open_close.columns = ['Open', 'Close']
forex_open_close['Day Change'] = forex_open_close['Close'] - forex_open_close['Open']
print(forex_open_close.head())
```

Comment: I think this is a job for a slicer. See the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers)

Answer (score 1):

Ok with credit to [ChuHo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6883295/chuho)

The following code solves my problem

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
print(forex_open_close.loc[idx[:,['AUDARS']], :])
```

And gives this output :

```
                      Open    Close  Day Change
Date       Symbol
11-01-2018 AUDARS  14.6193  14.7489      0.1296
12-01-2018 AUDARS  14.7486  14.7758      0.0272
```